# receive value in mvc5 controller from json post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Please check the code bellow. I am getting collection some Order ids and with a aditional value of its status which is string. But on my mvc5 controller this value not receiving. Controller is hitting but the model value is null. Whats wrong i am doing here? Do i need to change model some other way?

C# Model:

```
 public class ChangeOrderStatus
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<int> OrderIds { get; set; }
    }
```

mvc5 controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeStatus(ChangeOrderStatus ChangeOrderStatus)
{
  //this is the post controller not hitting on that json 
}
```

Json i am sending:

```
[{"Status":"Pending"},{"OrderIds":"9"},{"OrderIds":"3"}]
```

Jquery:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#btnConfirm", function () {
            var OrderStatus = $("#OrderStatus").val();
            //console.log(OrderStatus);

            var allSelectedProductIdWithKey = [];
            allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push({ Status: OrderStatus });
            $('.chkItems:checked').each(function () {
                allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push({ OrderIds: $(this).val() });
            });
            var things = JSON.stringify(allSelectedProductIdWithKey);

            console.log(things);//out from this looks like this: [{"Status":"Pending"},{"OrderIds":"9"},{"OrderIds":"3"}]

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Orders/ChangeStatus',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: things,

                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == 'ok') {
                        alert("Success! Order created");
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        alert("Error! Order not created. Something wrong");
                    }
                },

                error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            });


        });
```

Comment: try sending `var things = JSON.stringify({Status:"value1", OrderIds: [1,2,3]});`

Comment: In the JSON you are sending, Status and OrderIds don't belong to the same object. Try: `[{Status:"Pending", OrderIds:["9","3"]}]`

Comment: `var oRequest = {}; oRequest["Status"] = OrderStatus. var allSelectedProductIdWithKey = [];          
            $('.chkItems:checked').each(function () {
                allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push({ $(this).val() });
            }); oRequest["OrderIds"] = allSelectedProductIdWithKey;  ` - Try this modiifed snippet in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

making the object according to your Model class and stringify just as you call Ajax.

```
$("#btnConfirm").on("click", function () {
            var OrderStatus = $("#OrderStatus").val();
            //console.log(OrderStatus);
            var allSelectedProductIdWithKey = [];

            var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];



            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
                allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push(arr[i]);
            }


            //allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push({ Status: OrderStatus });
            //$('.chkItems:checked').each(function () {
            //    allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push({ OrderIds: $(this).val() });
            //});


            //var things = JSON.stringify(allSelectedProductIdWithKey);

            var things = {
                Status: OrderStatus,
                OrderIds: allSelectedProductIdWithKey
            };



            $.ajax({
                url: '/Orders/ChangeStatus',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(things),

                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == 'ok') {
                        alert("Success! Order created");
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        alert("Error! Order not created. Something wrong");
                    }
                },

                error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            });


        });
```

Please, modify it as you wish...

In the Controller, maybe better to send back JsonResult:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ChangeStatus(ChangeOrderStatus ChangeOrderStatus)
        {
            var result = "NOK";

            try
            {
                // ..............  Your code here

                result = "ok";
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```